# Play Store rejects my app for sensitive permissions

Tags: android, permissions

I'm submitting my app today, with the same permissions of one week ago, but Play Store rejects it with message:

Error
Your app cannot be released because the following APKs use sensitive permissions that have not been declared: 2. If you wanted to do a gradual implementation, you will need to do a full implementation.

The permissions are these (from one year):

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.NFC" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

I don't understand what permission is, and why I have this message.

Comment: Are you using a library that might still be using a sensitive permission that is getting merged in to your manifest file. I believe if you look in `app/build/intermediates/manifests/full/debug/AndroidManifest.xml` after the build you'll see the merged manifest), see if there's any extra permissions in there, then you'll need to figure out which library it is - that part might not be too easy

Comment: my understanding of the error message is that you're missing some permissions (permissions not declared in your manifest). Check the list here https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/permissions/overview#permission-groups and think whether you're app should be requesting more permissions than the ones declared. Also under special permissions the following two are described as "particularly sensitive": SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW and WRITE_SETTINGS. Check your code for use of these two and if you find anything declare it in the manifest.

Comment: I've checked all permission even in intermediates generated manifest file, but nothing....I've another similar app with same permissions, I've tried to submit it now and it go (with WRITE_SETTINGS moreover)....boh